# MVC application Viewengine not looking in Areas/{name}/Views instead looking in default Views folder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using 2017 VC for mac, the xamarian version of vs does not have the auto Areas Mapper. I manually added Areas folder and configured the routing properly, when I add an actionLink to my main csHTML page it is throwing an 500 error and stating.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The view 'Billing' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/BillingMain/Billing.cshtml
~/Views/BillingMain/Billing.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Billing.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Billing.vbhtml
~/Views/BillingMain/Billing.aspx
~/Views/BillingMain/Billing.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Billing.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Billing.ascx
```

Instead it should be searching in `~/Areas/Billing/Views/BillingMainController.cshtml`

I have tried everything to get this to work, but only keep on getting stuck.

Here is my directory hierarchy

```
Project-
    AppStart-
    Areas-
        Billing-
        Invoice-
    Controllers-
    Scripts-
    Views-
    Global.asax
```

I am only testing Billing area for now, below is the rest of my code.

RouteConfig

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WORK_GODDAMN
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                //,namespaces: new string[] { "WORK_GODDAMN.Areas.Controllers" }
            );

        }
    }
```

}

BillingAreaRegistration.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WORK_GODDAMN.Areas.Billing
{

    public class BillingAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Billing";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Billing_Default",
                "Billing/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "BillingMain", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                , namespaces: new string[] { "WORK_GODDAMN.Areas.Billing.Controllers" }
            );

        }   
    }



}
```

Global.asax

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WORK_GODDAMN
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

main _Layout.cshtml this is where the Action Link redirects and believe I might be doing something wrong here, but at this point I have no clue what could be causing the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    @using System.Web.Optimization
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/modernizr.js")
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>{Demo}- Pluggable Modules</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            @Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Home", new {Area=""}, null) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Invoice","Index","InvoiceMain", new {Area=""}, null) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Billing","Index","BillingMain", new {Area=""}, null)
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div>
                @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.js")
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Folder hierarchy]

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access ?

Comment: `localhost:8080/BillingMain` which should be routed to the `Views/Billing/BillingMainController`

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have the area name in the url ? Currently it is not hitting the area controller i guess. try `Billing/BillingMain`

Comment: that results in a `404` not found error? I tried that before since that is logically where its supposed to map to, but to not avail. I had to manually create the Areas folder since VS mac 2017 does not have add->Areas option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it was in my controller that the error was happening. Instead of returing `return View("Index")` I just gave the absolute path `return View("~/Areas/Billing/Views/Index.cshtml")` which is sort of a work-around, which is the only thing I found would work.

Also in the future if anyone wants to use html action link and model tags, you will need to manually add Web.Config file in both Areas/{area}/Views and Areas folder so you can use MVC framework in your cshtml View file. ***THIS IS FOR ANYONE WHO HAD TO MANUALLY CREATE AREAS*** if you use VS tool to add->Areas VS will automatically generate required files if you have VS do it, since Im using Mac Xamarin VS I don't have that convenient option.

This is what I had to change.

In {Project/Areas/Billing/Views/Index.cshtml} Change

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace WORK_GODDAMN.Controllers
{

    public class BillingMainController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Billing/BillingMain

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

TO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace WORK_GODDAMN.Controllers
{

    public class BillingMainController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Billing/BillingMain

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("~/Areas/Billing/Views/BillingMain/Index.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your have `BillingMain` controller inside the Billing area, you should explicitly specificity the area name when using the ActionLink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Billing","Index","BillingMain", new {Area="Billing"}, null)
```

This will generate the link with href value pointing to `yourSiteBaseAddress/Billing/BillingMain/Index`

Assuming you do not have any customer route definitions to override the default conventions, it should work as long as you have the view file  `Index.cshtml` in `~/Areas/Billing/Views/BillingMain/` or `~/Areas/Billing/Views/Shared/` (Assuming you are not trying to return a different view file from the Index action)

Comment: I am still getting 404 not found error, when I specify the Area explicitly in the ActionLink. I do have a `Index.cshtml` in `~/Areas/Billing/Views/BillingMain`

Comment: you are getting a 404 when trying to access `yourSiteBaseAddress/Billing/BillingMain/Index` ?

Comment: For some reason I think the Areas are not being registered properly thus the view-engine is searching in the default folder, and me being new to VS I am not sure how the debugging process really goes.

Comment: Yes I am still getting `404` when I access `localhost:8080/Billing/BillingMain/Index`

Comment: I will add a picture of my folder with everything expanded

Comment: I can add more information/data pertaining to this if you feel like the problem would exist somewhere else

Comment: Do you have any attribute routing which is overriding the conventional route patterns ?

Comment: other than the default route I have nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the name of area in Html.ActionLink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Billing", "Index", "BillingMain", new { Area = "Billing" }, null)
```